# GAE datastore entity ReferenceProperty() for user?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
class User(db.Model):
    username = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    password = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email_address = db.StringProperty()

class TaskPost(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='taskposts')
    category = db.StringProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Trying to use one-to-many relationship with the entities.
If you add a post, it will associate to a user.

```
user = User(username=self.request.cookies.get("username"))
TaskPost(user=user,others=others).put()

  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 641, in validate
    raise BadValueError('Property %s is required' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property password is required
```

So it seems it is not the best way to associate a user table with a post because user shouldn't input password when posting. Anyone has a better way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're implementing your own user object?

Comment: Use sessions, hash it, store it encrypted in the cookie with some seed and so on.

Comment: I want to be able to create a user profile with avatar and other values. It seems it is easier to create my own user object.

Answer (score 2):

Your first line isn't retrieving a user, it's creating a new one. If you want to associate the post with an existing user, you need to look up your user first and then associate them. Try something like this:

```
q = User.all()
q.filter("username =", self.request.cookies.get('username'))
user = q.get()
TaskPost(user=user,others=others).put()
```